# OSGI: Using code in another bundle from a fragment

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-fragment

I want to add an OSGI fragment to a bundle, here to "org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty", with a Manifest.mf like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: JettyCustomize
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.company.st.console.jetty.customize
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: Company
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty
```

Unfortunately, my code needs code defined in other bundles, here in "org.eclipse.jetty.io". So I add the following line to the manifest:

```
Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.io
```

Now - in Eclipse - the code compiles. But when I start the application, I get the following exception (`MyJettyCustomizer` is a class in the fragement that is used by the code in the fragment-host "org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty" per reflection):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.st.console.jetty.customize.MyJettyCustomizer cannot be found by org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.4.0.v20170503-2025
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager.createJettyCustomizer(HttpServerManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager.updated(HttpServerManager.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1628)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1608)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1579)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

If I remove the code that needs "org.eclipse.jetty.io" from `MyJettyCustomizer` and remove the line "Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.io" again from the manifest, there is no exception on runtime and the class `MyJettyCustomizer` is correctly loaded.

So is there any possibility that I can use code from another bundle in an OSGI fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have `com.company.st.console.jetty.customize` package in more than one bundle/fragment? It looks like split package issue!